# Not able to add WCF behavor extension to endpoint behaviors

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, behavior, endpointbehavior

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
          <add name="WSDLFlatteningExtension" type="Thinktecture.ServiceModel.Extensions.Description,Thinktecture.ServiceModel.Extensions.Description,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=Neutral,PublicKeyToken=f0de9a190a6d23d1"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WSDLFlatteningBehavior">
          <WSDLFlatteningExtension />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>    
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

`<WSDLFlatteningExtension />` line above is not recognized in my web.config. Throws an error at runtime. I have dropped the dll in C:\windows\Assembly and also in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What exact error does it throw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue. It was an issue with the dll I was referencing. I had to implement BehaviorExtensionElement in that class to make it available in configuration.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am unable to resolve it. I am not able to understand your answer. Could you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the error is an AssemblyNotFoundException then you could try also adding a DependentAssembly reference to your config file so the framework can resolve the AssemblyName specified in type.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the type name specified in your `type=` attribute - it doesn't look right to me. You need to specify the fully qualified name of the `IEndpointBehavior` type you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the type= attribute looks wrong to me too. It should be something like type="Your.Full.Namespace.ClassName,Your.Assembly.Name,Version,Culture,PublicKeyToken".

[Example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx):

```
type="Microsoft.WCF.Documentation.EndpointBehaviorMessageInspector, HostApplication, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```